# How do I update a ProgressBar using a Handler?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-handler

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to work through a tutorial on using a `ProgressBar` in conjunction with a `Handler`.  Just a note, I am targeting API 11.

Here is my code with the errors I am getting inline:

```
public class HandlerDemo extends Activity {

    ProgressBar bar;
    Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage() {   // Shows "method must override or implement supertype method" on this line.
            bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {

        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord arg0) {

        }
    };

    AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_handler_demo);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_handler_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bar.setProgress(0);

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 20 && isRunning.get(); i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage()); // Shows "Method is undefined for type Handler" on this line.
                    }
                } catch(Throwable t) { }
            }
        });
        isRunning.set(true);
        background.start();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isRunning.set(false);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Handler` import is wrong. It should be `android.os.Handler`

Comment: it shows warning also handler class must be static or leaks may occur

Comment: thnx buddy...it worked i was messed up with ctrl+shft+o thing...thnx a lot

Comment: If this problem is answered, I would suggest accepting the answer and posting a new question with your updated code and the logcat of the error.